# Resize parent control from child's resize event

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I'm starting work updating an UI for one of my company's applications and I'm running into a sticky issue. The parent control contains several panels, each of which can be turned on or off depending on user input.

The final panel in the user control contains another user control which gets resizes according to a toggle switch. Essentially, it "opens" up more information.

While the child control (ChildControl) is docked to Fill inside the parent control (ParentControl), when I add height to ChildControl I can't get ParentControl's height to get updated as well. Currently I'm handling the `ChildControl.Layout` event in ParentControl but I can't seem to reach that code. To resize ChildControl, I'm calling `Me.Height += 200` in ChildControl.vb.

I believe I'm doing this wrong, but MSDN isn't being much help. Thanks for any and all help.

Comment: You definitely don't want to use Dock, that forces the control to follow the size of the parent.  The parent should have AutoSize = True and AutoSizeMode = GrowAndShrink so it follows the child control.

Comment: I wish I could...I'm using a 3 year old release of Telerik controls, and the control is docked inside of a `RadGroupBox`. Apparently it has no support for `AutoSizeMode`. I can't wait until we finally rebuild this thing.

Comment: I did take your advise and got rid of the dock. Works much better, even without `AutoSizeMode`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the `ChildControl.Resize` event.

My answer is in C#. But it might work the same.

Comment: I should have mentioned this before, but I tried calling `ChildControl.Resize` `ChildControl.Layout` and `ChildControl.SizeChanged` events from `ParentControl.vb`

Comment: @DrFeelgood "when I add height to ChildControl..." – Why are you doing that if it's docked to `Fill`? Maybe you should undock it first. `label1.Dock = DockStyle.None;` in C#.

Comment: @DrFeelgood I just `Dock`ed a label in a form and the `Resize` event _did_ fire, but the `Height` remained the same (because it's docked, I assume.)

Comment: I got it to work, for whatever reason `SizeChanging` wasn't working before but after a few new builds it did. Sorry for the trouble!