# I have a UserControl which contains TextBox in C#?

Tags: c#, user-controls, textbox, size, height

When i increase the control Font size the textbox size only increasing or Decreasing.But the Container Size is not Increasing or Decreasing.

Updated...

```
public override Font Font
    {
        get
        {
            return base.Font;
        }
        set
        {
            base.Font = value;
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you post your code..

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5853073/change-the-textbox-height

Comment: @Inisheer On WinForm Font size should be set...,not dynamically

Comment: possible duplicate of [Resize parent control from child's resize event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8805085/resize-parent-control-from-childs-resize-event) and [c# Resize parent control when a child pictureBox changes the Image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11527680/c-sharp-resize-parent-control-when-a-child-picturebox-changes-the-image)

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement Resize event of textbox to resize its parent size, because it is not possible to auto adjust size of parent from its child controls.